# Fabric code asking for hosts

Tags: python, django, fabric

```
from fabric.api import env, sudo
def get_hostname():
    env.hosts = ['user@host_ip']
    env.passwords = {'user@host_ip': 'password'}
    hostname = run_cmd('hostname')
    print hostname


def run_cmd(cmd):
    return sudo(cmd)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_hostname()
```

This code is not working it is saying:

> No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:

Comment: There is a "tick" mark below the downvote, on the left side of every answer. you need to select most suitable answer for your question and tick that mark. this way it helps other too.

Comment: you welcome. keep sharing knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `get_hostname` will not be called unless you specify it in the fab arguments, calling it under `if __name__ == '__main__'` will not do what you think it does because a fabfile is not like a usual python script.

What you have to do is call your fabfile like this: `fab get_hostname run_cmd` and to have a more consistent error you can use [require](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.4/api/core/operations.html?highlight=require#fabric.operations.require) function like this:

```
from fabric.api import require


def run_cmd():
    require('hosts', provided_by=[get_hostname])
```

Comment: actually I have to execute it in django when user enters creds i need to verify if those creds are correct or not is there anyway I can do that ?

Comment: I am using paramiko to get that functionality and it works just fine